# WP hook isn't being called

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't get a Wordpress hook to fire.  I defined the hook in my functions.php in my theme:

```
add_action( 'download_rss', function() {
    error_log("Ran download_rss hook");
    file_put_contents('/nas/content/live/site/cron-task-runtime.txt', date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'));
});
```

Then I try to call it from a script on the root of my server using:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');
do_action('download_rss');
```

Yet when I go to the error log on the website I don't see that the hook has run.   What am I doing wrong and how can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The order of add_action() and do_action() is important. you have to make sure that you are calling do_action after registering action.

To be save, you can call your do_action inside another wrapper function at your theme's functions.php, like..

```
add_action( 'download_rss', function() {
   error_log("Ran download_rss hook");
   file_put_contents('/nas/content/live/site/cron-task-runtime.txt', date('l jS  \of F Y h:i:s A'));
});


add_action('wp_loaded', function(){
  do_action('download_rss');
})
```

and then, load the `wp-load.php` file where you need. Also make sure all file paths are valid when you are loading.

This should work, or, I could tell more if you provide what error log you are getting.